# ant sql insert statement fails on '--' strings. workaround?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, ant

**Context**

We're changing our install scripts to use ant's "sql" task and jdbc rather than proprietary sql clients sqlplus (oracle) and osql (msft).

Updated: added more context. Our "base data" (seed data) consists of a collection of .sql files containing "vendor-neutral"(i.e. works both in oracle and mssql) sql statements.

**The Problem**

The scripts run fine, with one exception:

This sql fails in Oracle. Specifically, something (ant or jdbc driver) treats the dashes/hyphens as "beginning of a comment"--even though they are embedded in a string. Note that the same sql works fine with ant/sql and microsoft's jdbc driver.

```
INSERT INTO email_client (email_client_id,generated_reply_text) VALUES(100002,'----- Original Message -----');
```

**Related Bug**

This [ant bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27739) appears to identify the problem.  As it's still open (after 8 years), I'm not hoping for a fix soon. However, because the problem appears only in oracle,  it may lie with the driver.

The oracle driver: jdbc thin driver, version 10.2.0.1.0

**The Question**

Does anyone have a workaround which works in both mssql and oracle? (e.g. changing the offending lines to define an escape character? I don't see an 'escape' on the 'insert' sql92 syntax)

thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to have empty columns in your column list? `(email_client_id,generated_reply_text,)`

Comment: mea culpa. I hand-edited/shortened a longer sql statement for brevity, but left some errors. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Are you able to replace these dashes with some sort of encoding? Such as `char(45)` or `&ndash`?

Comment: You say it fails in Oracle but at the same time you say it works in "*ant/sql*". So how can it fail when the SQL works in Ant?

Comment: to clarify:
the statement succeeds when run with the following: osql (msft), sqlplus (oracle), and Ant's Sql task (with microsoft jdbc drivers). it fails when run with: ant sql task (with oracle jdbc driver)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After viewing the 'SQLExec' source and turning on verbose logging, I found a workaround:

**Workaround**

*if the sql statement includes a string containing '--', place the delimiter (semi-colon) on the next line.*

**This Fails**

```
INSERT INTO email_client (email_client_id,generated_reply_text) VALUES(100002,'----- Original Message -----');
```

**This Succeeds**

Note that semi-colon is on a separate line

```
INSERT INTO email_client (email_client_id,generated_reply_text) VALUES(100002,'----- Original Message -----')
;
```

**Details**

Turning on verbose logging, I saw that when Ant came across the offending sql statement, it actually passed three sql statements in at once to the jdbc driver. The offending statement, the next statement (which also included an embedded '--'), and the subsequent statement (which did not include an embedded '--').

I gave the Ant code a quick glance and didn't see any obvious errors. Since I wasn't planning to patch Ant, I looked for a workaround.

Tweaking with it I found that if I simply moved the delimiter (semicolon) to the next line for the statements with embedded '--', the scripts executed successfully.

thanks everyone for weighing in

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
INSERT INTO email_client (email_client_id,generated_reply_text)
VALUES(100002,LPAD('-',5,'-') || ' Original Message ' || LPAD('-',5,'-'));
```

Comment: Our script files run vendor-agnostic sql. As MSSQL lacks the "lpad" function, we cannot try this approach. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: well, you tagged this "oracle"... whatever :)