# ORA-00911 Error when using double hyphen in comment

Tags: sql, oracle, comments, ora-00911

I have encountered an Problem on my Oracle 11 Express installation running on Windows Xp 32Bit.

When I run a SQL-Script via Ant an Ora-00911 error is thrown every time when I use a double hyphen. When I run the exactly same code on my Oracle installation on Unix it works like a charm.

This is my query:

```
comment on table X.TABLE is 'Commenttest -- Testingtable';
```

Is there any configuration that must be adapted? It seems to me that there is some kind of syntax check that thinks there is an SQL-Comment inside the comment-text.

Any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: I think this is a bug in Ant: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43413  so you might want to try `keepformat="true"` Btw: +1 for using database comments!

Comment: This is probably Ant problem

See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469496/ant-sql-insert-statement-fails-on-strings-workaround

Comment: thanks, keepformat="true" solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an Ant bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43413

You need to include the attribute `keepformat="true"` in your sql task:

```
<sql driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     url="jdbc:oracle:thin....."
     userid="scott"
     password="tiger"
     keepformat="true">

   comment on table foo is 'Commenttest -- Testingtable';
</sql>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing the closing single quote:

```
comment on table X.TABLE is 'Commenttest -- Testingtable';
                                                        ^----add this single quote
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, the missing single quot was an copy error. I have it in my statement and I corrected my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the terminating quote, please add as below:

```
     comment on table X.TABLE is 'Commenttest -- Testingtable';
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, the missing single quot was an copy error. I have it in my statement and I corrected my original post.

Comment: @Eyeless Did you try using the escape character `\` in front of the hyphens?